# Specify SMTP password manually on Amazon SES

Tags: email, amazon-web-services, password, credentials, amazon-ses

I have a requirement to specify 6-digit SMTP password on Amazon SES account for some reasons. But during SMTP credentials generation I have no choice and it is autogenerated, somewhere 32+ characters.
Is there any way to specify it explicitly?

Comment: No, there isn't, but there might be a suitable workaround, perhaps with some kind of proxy system... but to evaluate that, can you explain why you have a 6 digit requirement? Six characters isn't much of a password.

Comment: Probably (I don't know for sure) my router accept only small passwords in smtp settings. And I want to approve or disapprove this is a reason if sending failure